# DB2 INSERT INTO SELECT statment to copy rows into the same table not allowing multiple rows

Tags: db2, sql-insert, self-join

I've been looking for an answer to this question for a few days and can't find anything referencing this specific issue.

First of all, should it work if I want to use an INSERT INTO SELECT statement to copy over rows of a table, back into the same table but with new id's and 1 of the column modified?

Example:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE_A (column1, column2, column3) SELECT column1, 'value to change', column3 from TABLE_A where column 2 = 'original value';
```

When I try this on a DB2 database, I'm getting the following error:

> INVALID MULTIPLE-ROW INSERT. SQLCODE=-533, SQLSTATE=21501, DRIVER=4.18.60

If I run the same statement but I put a specific ID to return in the select statement, ensuring only 1 row is returned, then the statement works.  But that goes against what I'm trying to do which is copy multiple rows from the same table into itself, while updating a specific column to a new value.

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention your platform and version, but the docs seems pretty clear..

[IBM LUW 11.5](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.messages.doc/doc/rdb2stt.html#rsttmsg__code21)

> A multiple-row INSERT into a self-referencing table is invalid.

[First google results](http://www.sqlerror.de/db2_sql_error_-533_sqlstate_21501.html)

> An INSERT operation with a subselect attempted to insert multiple rows
>   into a self-referencing table. The subselect of the INSERT operation
>   should return no more than one row of data. System action: The INSERT
>   statement cannot be executed. The contents of the object table are
>   unchanged. Programmer response: Examine the search condition of the
>   subselect to make sure that no more than one row of data is selected.

**EDIT**  You've apparently got a self-referencing constraint on the table.  Ex: EMPLOYEES table with a MANAGER column defined as a FK self-referencing back to the EMPLOYEES table.

Db2 simply doesn't support what you are trying to do.

You need to a temporary table to hold the modified rows.

Optionally, assuming that your table has a primary key, try using the `MERGE` statement instead.

Comment: "First google results" is not always the best place to go.  Official manual page for SQLCODE=-533  for Db2 (LUW) is  https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.messages.sql.doc/com.ibm.db2.luw.messages.sql.doc-gentopic3.html#sql0533n   and that is a somewhat different error than the one you quoted

Comment: @PaulVernon I did include a link to the offical Db2 docs (based on SQLSTATE instead of SQLCODE.  They all same the same thing.

Comment: Sorry Charles, my eyes skipped to the "First google results"  in your post and missed the first link. I'm not sure about the veracity of that website. It says on the front page that "This is a free Service. I assume no warranty for misprints, and for the correctness and completeness of information and entries.",  but not much else in the way of explanation about what the service actually is.

Answer (score 0):

It works fine for me without error on Db2 11.1.4.0

```
CREATE TABLE TABLE_A( column1 int , column2 varchar(16), column3 int)

INSERT INTO TABLE_A values (1,'original value',3)

INSERT INTO TABLE_A (column1, column2, column3)
SELECT column1, 'value to change', column3 from TABLE_A where column2 = 'original value'

SELECT * FROM TABLE_A
```

returns

```
COLUMN1|COLUMN2        |COLUMN3
-------|---------------|-------
      1|original value |      3
      1|value to change|      3
```

maybe there is something you are not telling us....

Comment: Read the docs, the error occurs when there's a self-referencing constraint on the table.  Which the OP doesn't mention.

Comment: @Charles [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=db2_11.1&fiddle=51a65dd4d45f4cfea6f38e351359f74a) link. It works well on Db2 for LUW. TS should probably describe how he/she got such an error.

Comment: Agreed. I was hoping the OP might take the hint and give use a better reproduction of their issue.  I did not have the time myself to try to reproduce the error based on a self-referencing constraint on the table, was hoping the OP could hlep